# Proactively Triggering a Health Bot Scenario Through Code Throws an Error

Tags: javascript, c#, direct-line-botframework, web-chat, microsoft-health-bot

I think it has something to do with the json web token that's causing the error.  I think I may have created the json web token incorrectly but not 100% sure.  And if I did create it incorrectly, not sure where I screwed up on.  I'm stuck on this part.  Any help is much appreciated.

On a side note, this is a Microsoft MVC web application project that uses .NET Core 3.1.  This is for a web chat that is connected to the Microsoft Health Bot.  The client-side javascript code is based on the [Health Bot Container Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/blob/master/public/index.js) code.

**Objective:**
To proactively trigger a Microsoft Health Bot scenario through javascript code.

**Error response received on client-side:**
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ().

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Missing token or secret"
  }
}
```

**Server-side C# Code:**

```cs
using ........
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
```

```cs
private string GenerateJsonWebToken()
{
    // Using the direct line secret key, create a new
    // symmetric security key instance.
    var tmpSecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretKey");
    SymmetricSecurityKey tmpSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(tmpSecretKey);

    // Using the symmetric security key, create a new 
    // signing credential instance.
    SigningCredentials tmpSigningCreds = new SigningCredentials(tmpSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

    // New claims collection that contains some user info.
    List<Claim> tmpClaims = new List<Claim>();
    tmpClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, "userId"));
    tmpClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "userName"));

    // JWT security token instance.
    JwtSecurityToken tmpSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: tmpClaims, signingCredentials: tmpSigningCreds);

    // JWT security token handler to create json web tokens.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tmpSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    string tmpResult = tmpSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(tmpSecurityToken);

    return tmpResult;
}
```

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Security token.
    ViewBag.JsonWebToken = GenerateJsonWebToken();

    // Scenario to launch when the web chat is launched.
    ViewBag.AutomaticWelcomeScenario = this._automaticWelcomeScenario;

    return View();
}
```

**Client-side Javascript code:**

```js
const tmpJWT = "@ViewBag.JsonWebToken";

// Create our own store where we could specify a scenario to use as an automatic welcome scenario
// to greet the user when the web chat is first started up.
// Sample code:
// https://github.com/microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/blob/master/public/index.js
var tmpStore = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function (store) {

    return function (next) {
        return function (action) {

            if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {

                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY',
                    meta: { method: 'keyboard' },
                    payload: {
                        activity: {
                            type: "invoke",
                            name: "InitConversation",
                            locale: "en-US",
                            value: {

                                // Must use for authenticated conversation.
                                jsonWebToken: tmpJWT,

                                // Use the following activity to proactively invoke a bot scenario.
                                triggeredScenario: {
                                    trigger: "@ViewBag.AutomaticWelcomeScenario",
                                    args: {
                                        myVariable1: "Test Value 1",
                                        myVariable2: "Test Value 2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return next(action);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: So all you're trying to do is start your bot when Web Chat loads? Doesn't Health Bot do that automatically? I'm confused about what sort of custom functionality you're trying to implement

Comment: hi @KyleDelaney, you are correct.  the admin site of the health bot on the "Interactions" tab of the "Configuration -> Conversation" page, one is able to set the "Automatic welcome scenario" by choosing a certain scenario from a drop down.  So through the UI, we can do that.  I was trying to figure out how to do that but through the javascript code.  

I was finally able to get it working with the help from some Microsoft SMEs on this.  

I found out that I did not need to use a json web token due to this not being an authenticated conversation.  I missed that part.  Everything is okay now

Comment: Would you like to post that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with Microsoft's help.  Because the chat conversation is not an authenticated conversation, I won't need the json web token.  After I took out the usage of the json web token, it worked.  I was able to load a specific scenario through code upon the launch of the web chat.